# Extracting the week from python datetime and getting the serial number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with column name order date containing date from July 2014 to June 2015 in the format 2014-10-17 15:11:54. Using datetime I have extracted the week number from the date. However I get the starting week as 27 for July 2014 than for January 2015 starts again as week 1. What I want is July 2014 as week 1 continue till June 2015 and ends as 53.

```
df['Week'] = df.order_date.dt.week
```

Use the above code to get the week number after that to get as 1 for July 2014 use

```
def time_period(x):
    if df.Week >= 26:
        return df.Week -25
    else:
        return df.Week +28
df['week_serial'] = df.Week.apply(lambda x: time_period(x))
```

This gives an error- The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0):

Well since `df.Week` already contains the week number, the function should look like:

```
def time_period(x):
    if x >= 26:
        return x-25
    else:
        return x+28
```

But I think you here basically are looking for a modulo operation:

```
df['week_serial'] = (df['Week'] + 27) % 53 + 1
```

This will map `26` on `1`, `27` on `2`, etc.; and `25` on `53` and `24` on `52`, etc.

So for sample input:

```
>>> df
   Week
0    13
1    49
2    47
3    12
4    35
5    17
6     1
7    46
8    19
9     0
```

we obtain:

```
>>> (df['Week'] + 27) % 53 + 1
0    41
1    24
2    22
3    40
4    10
5    45
6    29
7    21
8    47
9    28
Name: Week, dtype: int64
```

Comment: it worked but it should be +26 not +27 @Willem Van Onsem

Comment: @NadeemHaque: but then the original question is not entirely correct. The `(df['Week'] + 27) % 53 + 1` is in "harmony" with the `def time_period(x):` you provided. So then that function likely is not entirely correct?

Comment: time_period(x) is from 26

Comment: @NadeemHaque: yes that is true, but we use an extra `+1` to compensate for the modulo wraparound.

Comment: yes agree but that +1 adds up to the next week which results in 2 instead of 1

Answer (score 0):

Given that you already have `datetime.datetime` objects, it is probably the easiest to use those.

First, define your start date.

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: start  = datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 1)
Out[2]: datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 1, 0, 0)
```

Then determine the `timedelta` between each date and the start, and convert that to days and then weeks.

```
In [3]: (datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 24) - start).days
Out[3]: 266

In [4]: (datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 24) - start).days // 7 + 1
Out[4]: 39
```